# Stripe Android - Scan Card

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I'm working on integrating stripe add card.

This is my XML code. I'm using "CardInputWidget" to get card details.

Is there any way to implement **scan card feature**? Any default method to enable scan card. Can anyone help me with this? Does stripe android SDK provide scan card feature

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey_300"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <include layout="@layout/actionbar_layout" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/citygoToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/emailInput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:hint="Enter your email" />

        <com.stripe.android.view.CardInputWidget
            android:id="@+id/cardInputWidget"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_white_border_shape" />

        <Button
            android:text="Save"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/payButton"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            style="@style/AppTheme.Button.Pink" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This currently isn't support in Stripe's Android SDK.

Comment: Stripe has officially launched their SDK for card scanning on Android, which is great news. You can find more infos [Here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/tree/master/stripecardscan)

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own button, say imageView with "camera_icon"

implement the library "io.card:android-sdk:5.4.2"

after that you can prepare the request

```
fun onClickScanCard() {
        val scanIntent = Intent(activity, CardIOActivity::class.java)

        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_HIDE_CARDIO_LOGO, true)
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SUPPRESS_MANUAL_ENTRY, true)
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_EXPIRY, false)
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_CVV, false)
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_POSTAL_CODE, false)
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_USE_PAYPAL_ACTIONBAR_ICON, false)

        activity.startActivityForResult(scanIntent, yourRequestCode)
    }
```

and handle the result. I use binding for set values into the fields you can use another way.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (requestCode == yourRequestCode && data?.hasExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SCAN_RESULT) == true) {
            val scanResult = data.getParcelableExtra<CreditCard>(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SCAN_RESULT)
            scanResult?.also { creditCard ->
                val expiryDate = creditCard.expiryMonth.toString() + creditCard.expiryYear

                binding.cardNumberEditText.setText(creditCard.cardNumber)
                binding.expiryDateEditText.setText(expiryDate)
                binding.zipCodeEditText.setText(creditCard.postalCode)
                binding.cvcEditText.setText(creditCard.cvv)
            }

            activity.storefrontAnalytics.onScannedCard()

            updateEnabledState()
        }
    }
```

Google recommends contracts to work with startForResult.

Answer (score 0):

Better use `CardScanSheet` from the official library, which [`stripe-android`](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android) provides:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:20.5.0'
    implementation 'com.stripe:stripecardscan:20.5.0'
}
```